nuxt3 deploying error 500, even on clean new installed project
Purpose:
build/deploy nuxt3 project and review it on my mac.
commands used: yarn build > node .output/server/index.mjs
error getting in terminal after navigating to url in browser:
[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Cannot find module '/Users/mark/Desktop/project/.output/server/node_modules/vue/server-renderer/index.mjs' imported from /Users/mark/Desktop/project/.output/server/chunks/handlers/renderer.mjs
  at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)  
  at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)  
  at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1157:11)  
  at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:390:12)  
  at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:359:25)  
  at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:234:38)  
  at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:87:39)  
  at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:86:36)

in dev mode everything works fine, yarn build doesn't throw any errors, then when running node .output/server/index.mjs and going to http://0.0.0.0:3000 in the browser i get error 500, i tried to install a new project with a clean nuxt app and after building the same error
system mac (sonoma 14.1)
node v20.12.2

Can you try node .output/server/index.mjs as stated at the end of the build command?

That's exactly what I did, sorry, I wrote the path incorrectly in the question, fixed that

i opened .output/server and ran command yarn install, its relink all dependencies also gives this warn
warning " > @vue/server-renderer@3.4.26" has incorrect peer dependency "vue@3.4.26".

and its work.
